# How can I animate a 2D face rig on any 3D object?

Tags: animation, materials

So I've been trying to animate 2D textures on a 3D mesh as in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY).

It was made on Blender 2.79 and the differences are driving me crazy.

Comment: Please be more specific! The tools of Blender 2.79 and 2.8 are very similiar if not the same. At what part are you stuck or what tool are you looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least 4 solutions:

***Texture Coordinate Object*** solution:

Create your facial expression on a transparent PNG, create an empty, use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node and select the empty at the bottom of the *Texture Coordinate* in order to control the location of the image. In the *Image Texture* node, choose *Clip* instead of *Repeat*. You can parent the empty to a bone if you want to keyframe more easily:

[image]

[image]

***UV Project modifier*** solution:

Create all the expressions on a trasparent image, create an empty, give your object a *UV Project* modifier with the empty as *Object*, use the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate*, move the empty to move the image on the surface. If you have another texture for the skin, simply create a second UV map and select it in a *UV Map* node, and select the first UV map in the modifier:

[image]

***UV Warp*** solution:

- Create a PNG, with transparent background, of your facial expressions:

[image]

- Give your object a material. Assign another material to the face area: Unwrap this part, add a *UV Map* node with the new UV map loaded, plug it into an *Image Texture* node, open the PNG, plug the *Image Texture* into a *Mix Shader*, plug the *Image Texture Alpha* output into the *Factor* of the *Mix Shader*, plug the skin material into the other input of the *Mix Shader*.

[image]

- Create an empty at the same position as the head. Give the head a *UV Warp* modifier. Choose X and Z as *UV Axis*, *From* > Choose the head object, *To* > Choose the empty.

[image]

- Create a bone at the exact same position as the empty. Parent the empty to this bone (the bone will probably be part of a whole armature):

[image]

- Now the bone controls the empty and the empty controls the position of the PNG. To save all the different expressions, you can use the Pose *Library* in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data*. Move the bone in *Pose* mode and press the "+" button to save the pose. Continue until you've saved all the poses. "+" button is also used to replace an existing pose. Use the *Apply* button to call a pose. Give each pose an appropriate name (*Smile*, *Sad*, etc...).

[image]

***Image Sequence*** solution:

- Create your facial expressions on transparent (alpha) backgrounds, name your images 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, etc:

[image]

- Select the part of your mesh where the expressions are supposed to happen, unwrap and give it its own material. Create an *Image Texture* node, click on its *Open Image* button, select and load all the PNGs, plug the node's color output into a *Mix Shader*, use the other *Mix Shader*' socket for the skin color you've used for the rest of the head, plug the *Image Texture*'s alpha output into the mix factor socket so that you can see the expressions over the skin:

[image]

- When you've imported your PNG, the *Image Texture* node has automatically switched to its *Image Sequence* mode. Set the *Frames* value to 1. Now you just need to create some keyframes on the *Offset* value to switch between the different images along the timeline. The *Offset* begins at 0, so *Offset* > 0 will be image 0, *Offset* > 1 will be image 1, etc. In the *Dopesheet*, once some keyframes created, press <kbd>T</kbd> and choose *Constant Interpolation* so that each keyframe switches directly to the image you want.

[image]

- It should work:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip! I actually had more information on my question but somehow the last two paragraphs got deleted ahahaha, I mentioned I tried in different modes and this one you showed might as well solve my problem! Thanks again, have a virtual hug from me! Oh wait, the virus, nevermind. Elbow touch!

Comment: there's also a simpler way to use the UV Warp, same modifier as in your video, I'll try to edit my answer tomorrow