# Want tips on lip animation based on texture

Tags: animation

Dears,
I created a mock movie scene animation in blender.
https://youtu.be/1u_2AOxVzgU
Any tips on how to do lip animations? I don't want to over complexify it, it will be just used as a small intro bit for my tech channel.
What are the different techniques you guys follow for this kind of animation projects?

Comment: I answered a similar question here, I hope it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object

Comment: @moonboots Thanks I will check the same.