# how to fix pupils (nodes)

Tags: mesh, texturing, node-editor, shaders, edit-mode

ive tried to make a black and white 2d mesh (the 2d mesh does have a curve however) i have used nodes to make a black, shiny mesh texture with glowing white pupils, however for some reason on my eye mesh the white pupils do not show,
[image]

on a plane mesh which is a 2d sphere, i get what im looking for when it comes to nodes, however if i try to bend this mesh in any way the pupils shrinks and disappears to the corner and cant be brought back.
[image]

this is the same mesh that i have moved with the sculpt tool
[image]

this is the mesh that i have made, this is the one that i need help with as the pupils do not show
[image]

the material says the pupils are there and yet there not, i know its something to do with the shape of my mesh probably however i need this exact shape for the rest of my character, so if you could help with this it would be most helpful, also this mesh does not have mirror modifier
[image]

[image]

it does work, it works well honestly, however though you mesh works fine, and mine works with it too[image]

however when i try to move t it shrinks, though i might be because of the orb controlling the pupils needs to stay close to the mesh, my mesh curves a lot[image]

[image]

this means the orb shrinks and disappears is there some way to control how far the pupil controller can be from the eye
[image]

besides from that the pupil works i just need to know if this new problem is easily solvable

Comment: hello please share your file so that we don't have to recompose the whole node setup: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: the blender file? ok were do i send it

Comment: use the link I've just given: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: done i have sent

Comment: you need to copy the URL and paste it here  ;)

Comment: have you recieved it?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/3/a/3a12aaeb004f0b592de8bb76b2d2ce8c.blend

Comment: You can change the settings so that the white cicle appears on your shape, but I guess the good solution also depends on what you want to do at the end, are the white pupils supposed to stay still, or will they move, does the eye shape change and bend, etc?

Comment: i am hoping to rig the eyes the eye shape will not change, the head will move when its is parented to the eyes so hopefully the movement wont effect the model, do you know what settings will fix the eye problem

Comment: so the pupil won't move on the surface? You can simply tweak the Maooing Location values

Comment: oh it will move on the surface , i thought you meant the whole eye, no the pupil will move

Comment: So how will you make the pupil move? You could use the Mapping Location values but there are other more convenient ways like using an empty as an Object in the Texture Coordinate or using the UV Warp modifier

Comment: wait, i have 1 more question, first of al, i used a bone to move both empty pupils so that works, how do i see the final thing in render preview

Comment: what do you mean? You should see the result in Rendered preview... unless there's a problem of UV map or something?

Comment: it works on the normal viewport shading but the second full rendered version doesn't appear, i mean i should, the eyes glow

Comment: maybe share your file (keep only the useful objects): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ok something odd is up, i went and put the eyes into a different blender file, clicked render and it looks completly different in render, but the pupils apear, its odd as i even brought my entire character model into the different blender file and even that looks different in the render view, on the file where they were originally, because my robot has glowing red mouth, it appears and glows over parts of his body and he is pitch black because i didn't add lighting yet, however when its in the other file, the render preview looks really bad and looks like normal preview render but wierder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is almost the same as @moonboots..

Your texture is based in Object space, and is a 3D spherical gradient. So the glowing volume (limited by the Color-Ramp) is a sphere around the object origin. What shows on the surface is its intersection with that sphere. As the surface  gets further away from the object origin, it intersects with less and less of the sphere, and eventually the glow disappears.

One option would be to put the texture in the space of another object, which you can do in the Texture Coordinate node, in the 'Object' slot.

[image]

Here,  Empties are used to locate the texture. They are [Vertex Parented](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#vertex-parent) to the surface, using 3 vertices near the middle. (You could use one vertex, if only the location of the Empty matters to you, and you don't want the orientation to follow the surface) The Empties, (and the sphere of texture around them) will now follow the surface when it is deformed.

This shader tree could be made in many ways depending on the effect you want.. the only important thing for this answer is that the texture is in the Object space of the parented Empty..

[image]

The attached .blend is hardly a rig.. but the Left (Camera-Right) Iris-Empty is Transform-Constrained to the Right Iris-Empty, so the right Iris controls both.

[image]

[image]

Edit: If you want the Empties to cling to the surface under substantiaal distortion, you can add a *Shrinkwrap* constraint at the bottom of their constraint stacks. How you project, and whether or not you want to keep the transform constraints... I don't know.. that depends on how you want to animate?

Revised .blend:

[image]

Comment: thanks this really helps and it works, however i edied the question above just so you can see if this small problem is do-able

Comment: Have a go at the suggestion in the edit.. works for me..  With parenting, transform _and_ shrinkwrap.. they may not interact in the way you need..  you may need to pick'n'mix.

Comment: ok the the first one and the second one works on the eye really well thank you, the only think i need help with now is to connect the non moving eye to the controller eye, right now both eyes control manually

Comment: basically the left of my eye mesh works fine but when i constrain it, the right eye only wants to move up, also the eye keeps facing left(not on left eye its just facing that direction

Comment: I'm using The second linked 'Revised' .blend, TexEyes2. I re-downloaded it, and I'm not getting this behaviour.. Hard to believe we're looking at the same file. Maybe share yours.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/ce4ffa6b56eb468f97115a35b77481fd

Comment: i copied everything onto my mesh and yet there's the issue, ur mesh works fine, i just cant figure out the problem with mine if you get me

Comment: @JustImpact   Sorry for late reply, I've had to do quite a bit of research to figure out why your version wasn't working. Still getting my head around it, but I've stress-tested a different way of assembling the rig, which, fingers crossed, should work for you, Instructions included in a text-file in [this version](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2qgW9wkW/)

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem is that you're deforming the object in 3D. The material setup, that works fine for a 2D object, will deform in 3D. You could fix that with the *Mapping* node, but as you want to animate the pupil, you need to find another solution, because animating with the *Mapping* node would be a bit tedious.

A quick way to do it is to create an empty, parent it to the head and give your *Texture Coordinate* the empty as *Object*:

[image]

Now when you move the empty the pupil follows. You can give it a *Limit Location* constraint (*Local Space* mode) so that it sticks around the eye area when you manipulate it:

[image]

[image]

A more accurate solution would be to give your eye an *Image Texture* and move the texture with the *UV Warp* modifier, see video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB9cJ3wOoPk) or Blender Stack Exchange answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object).

Comment: oh so you mean make the glow on the eye separate? do you have the model i sent, could you see if it works since im honestly very confused.

Comment: no it's not separate, you're just moving the material. Actually you don't specify in your question that you need to move the pupil, so your initial question is easily fixable with the Mapping location, but it looks like you also want to move the pupil so you need to find a solution for this and this is one among others

Comment: another one would be to create an image of the pupil on a black background, use it in an Image Texture node, and move it with the UV Warp modifier

Comment: i love how you did the eye in the gif, can you explain how to parent the eye in more detail

Comment: see the node setup, you just need to create an empty then choose it in the Texture Coordinate node, it will allow you to control the material location, which is more convenient than the Mapping node

Comment: i changed the nodes to what you did, i put it on the edited question, i added the empty, now what

Comment: now if you move the empty it should move the white circle. Does it work? Again, it's a quick method

Comment: if im doing it correctly then its not workingn look on image above

Comment: could you  resend the link its gone

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/cf1438ffabf740efab8ad9fa8dec9057

Comment: it only stated working when i re-did the thing however its quite distorted when you move its

Comment: Yes because the empty position will determine how the white circle is projected on the black surface, maybe the best method for you is the one I've linked here, a bit more tedious to make but it will make the control much easy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB9cJ3wOoPk

Comment: so does that mean if i do this tutorial i wont get my shiny glowing white eyes?

Comment: If you plug your Image Texture into an Emission shader it will glow. You could also keep the method I explain and constrain the empty on some axis with the Limit Location constraint, but I think it's a bit tedious; you should take a look at the other method. That said maybe someone has a simpler solution...

Comment: @Robin Betts, I don't see what you mean, maybe wirte an answer?

Comment: hi, i know @moonboots you helped me with this a while ago, just wondering how do you parent the second pupil to be parented to the first pupil, and have the pupils stay around the same equal positions they need to be in, had shrink wrapped the first pupil to the eye i made and it works well, i just nee the second one to correspond to it too. sorry for the hassle, its better me ask now than years later :P

Comment: hello, I'm not sure why you use Shrinkwrap, maybe ask a new question with details?

Comment: oh another thing too, you have different viewports, a wireframe, normal, rendered a little, and them full render viewport, how to i get the eyes to appear in viewport shader

Comment: again, maybe ask a brand new question, I don't understand your question  ^^

Comment: i really wish i could, but apparently i cant ask questions anymore, its not really good for a beginner because you just shutting them down from help really,

Comment: mmh ok, weird... or you can use BlenderArtists

Comment: ok i guess i can try that, thanks for help you gave me. hope you do well