# Blend shapes, but for textures/decals...?

Tags: rigging, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to understand how to rig a very simple figure/head with blend shapes to use through a animation framework in unity. Now I made the head so low poly that the actual facial features would mostly have to be textures sliding around. So I think I should understand and learn to use decals, but I suspect those might not be covered by blend shapes.

Can I use blend shapes for UV maps and/or decals or do I need to make a bunch of loop cuts in my low poly model as a workaround so I can use them?

---

***Edit:*** I understand the term blend shapes as a **collection of distortion maps** which can be **combined**, each weighted by a **factor**, to quickly produce complex distortions in a mesh. The term distortion map was made up by me to describe a **mapping of vectors** for each vertex in a mesh, describing the **offset** from its original position. This appears to be mostly used for facial and similar animations, where one tries to simulate organic shapes with many points which all move differently based on the surrounding points.

[image: A face model with different blend shapes applied individually]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by blend shapes? Maybe show some screenshots? Do you want to use image textures? In that case check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object

Comment: I tried to explain my understanding of them.
I found something similar to your link, but it does not allow me smooth transition between states or partial positions.