# What is the efficient way to make animation with material changing?

Tags: animation, materials, shaders

Okay, I'm new to blender and I'm making a simple project. I kind of not used to blender's term. Sorry if I'm not using the right terms. How do I keyframe and change a specific polygon on one object to new material in blender. Like this one for example
[image]
and changing it to
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *UV Warp* modifier, see [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object).

But the simplest way is probably to create all your facial expressions on a big picture, unwrap your object, give it a *(Input) Texture Coordinate > (Vector) Mapping > (Texture) Image Texture* node chain, and play with the Mapping XYZ location parameters to change the position of the picture on the object:

[image]

Another way, probably more convenient, is to use an empty and select it in the *Texture Coordinate "Object"* output in order to control the image, see answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240381/bake-image-into-texture-as-if-it-was-a-sticker/240393#240393):

[image]

[image]