# Moving a texture with UV warp modifier and an empty

Tags: animation, modifiers, uv, empty

I asked a question with an old account about moving eye textures and got an answer about using empties and the UV warp modifier. I cannot seem to find the question itself, so was wanting to know if anyone else knew how the process works. I'm trying to use it to be able to animate eye textures.

Comment: I've given some answers here, I hope it helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object

Comment: @moonboots you could post it here again, it would get accepted (since the question mentions it)

Comment: actually it's better to point to the page if the question has already been answered

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but here's a solution: Add an empty, and in the texture coordinate node (if you don't have one, add one and connect it into the vector of your textures, add a mapping node in between for more control over size/location/dimensions/rotation) of your material, there will be an object input. Select your empty from there and now if you move your empty the texture will move with it.

Comment: I've tried that solution, but all it does is mess up the texture.

Comment: @Ethan so you've lost access to your old account? Can you share some screenshots and the desired result? Because at one point you're saying "moving" eye textures, which you can do by animating the eye rotation in object mode, and at the other point you're saying animating the eye textures. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: What I mean is to use an empty to directly move the uv of the texture with it. The eyes are not spherical so rotation won't work.

Comment: @Ethan would you attach some screenshots of the eye and your material? Since technically this solution works. If it's possible, also kindly attach your .blend file :)

Comment: @Ethan also did you try placing the empty in the exact same location as the eyes first?

Comment: @Ethan Have you set your texture coordinate to object instead of UV? Of yes and it's happening, I guess there's another solution, I'll try to find out (though remember that you can always animate the mapping node's rotation or location properties.)

Comment: Here's a picture of how I set up my texture coordinates. The empty does nothing when I move it. https://imgur.com/a/MaQePpq

Comment: @Ethan connect the object output, not the UV output from the texture coordinate node.

Comment: So it appears to work, but the UVs get screwed and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @Ethan Did you check moonboots' answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object?