# Eye texture is distorted, iris and pupil are not fully circular

Tags: texturing, uv, image

[image]

The above image is the eye  I try to create, there i distortion for the iris and pupil.
[image] from front view

[image] from side view

the above image are the result I wish to achieve.

Note:

- the pupil and iris movement will be created using texture/UV animation.
- the shape, rotation and size of model is not allow to be change

Is there still a way to achieve the desire result

Blender file :[image]

[image]

Image texture

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I see no technical problem here that could be solved by an answer about using Blender. Eyeballs are usually round so they can rotate. They should be round so you can animate the rotation. If you want them to be another shape and want to animate the texture instead in a stylised way, then you should accept that it is going to be stylised and not realistic. I don't think this question has anything to do with Blender and usage of it. I think this is off topic.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys .. I don't know about that.. what is sought here is a way of sweeping the texture across the oviod geometry, while keeping it circular, which makes it a mapping problem, possibly solvable in a node-tree  ... or UV Project?

Comment: You might be right. One could project the texture based on camera position and move the projection to animate eye movement. Maybe a separate object with its rotation aimed at camera could be used for that projection... But is that really what the question means?.. @Kenny can you clarify and provide more context?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you and noted, I have edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ***UV Warp*** modifier as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object), it will allow you to control the iris position with an empty or bone, you'll have a bit of deformation but you can tweak a bit your UV map to limit it, here is a test:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, it is better than the approach I am going,  I never thought of this method before.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just [@moonboots' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/285242/35559), with notes. (I was slower off the mark.) So credit there, not here, please.

If you give your eye a *UVProject* modifier, aimed at a constrained Empty, you may find you need to scale the texture about an offset center:

[image]

From the Empty's point of view, the projected texture will always be undistorted. Here, the Empty is constrained with a *Damped Track* constraint to aim at the eye-object. So the intersection of the eye-surface and the projection can be adjusted, somewhat, by adjusting the eye's mesh with respect to its object origin.

[image]

You can construct the  rig at the origin, if you also parent the Empty to the eye. Here, the Empty also has a *Limit Location* constraint in its parent's (Local) space above the track, to stop the texture disappearing off the edge of the eye.

The rig can be duplicated, with the second Empty constrained to locally  *Copy Transforms* from the first:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, this is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Because eyes must rotate, they are always spherical (or almost) Your 3D eye model looks like a distorted or stretched sphere, that's why you get this result.