# I'm trying to create eyes in a specific art style, but most tutorials only show realistic-esque eyes

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting

I'm trying to create a character in the TMNT 2012 CGI style, and thus far the eyes have been the hardest to master; they look as though the iris' may be 2D shaded, but I am a mere novice at Blender, so I was hoping someone on this forum could help me out.
For reference for what I'm aiming for, I'm attaching a clip of the characters so you can get a general sense of movement and texture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQj5HX2WepA&t=150s

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello, yes it looks like it's a texture that is animated, for example with the UV Warp modifier, then put a glossy surface over the image. See answers here for example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object