# How would I make a character without a head have "face rotation" to show where it's looking?

Tags: rigging

I have a very simple mushroom character and i want to make a rig for it that allows the eyes to move around the cylindrical body to show where it's looking. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Here there are some solutions, if it doesn't fit with your needs please give more details or share your file: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object

Comment: The eyes are 3D objects that kind of protrude out of the face. I thought about using a constraint to limit them to the surface of the cylinder, but it unfortunately didn't work how I was expecting it to.

Comment: please show a screenshot of your object

Comment: so you can parent to a bone (or even to an empty) and rotate the bone? where do you struggle exactly?

Comment: i was just wondering if there was a way to make it so i can parent they eye bones to something and when i move the target, the eyes kind of slide around the body and rotate along with the cylinder, but still slide up and down on the body.

Comment: sure, the eyes bone can have a Track To constraint, but is the body supposed to deform or will it stay vertical?

Comment: body will likely stay solid, no bending or anything, but it will rotate along the x and y axis

Comment: So what about a bone with a Track To constraint and parent the eyes to this bone ? And parent this bone to a head bone that will control the cylinder?

Comment: The problem with that, I'm finding, is that when i move the eyes bone up or down, it rotates the bone, since it's trying to point at the origin of the cylinder. is there any way to make it only rotate on the z axis and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I have this rig:

[image]

Each eye have its deformation bone at the center of the head where they should rotate from, and child of the root bone.
You can have a main eyes controller, and individual eyes controllers child of the main, itself child of the head bone. That way you can use the main to control the eyes in one go, and use the individual eyes controllers for individual fine-tuning.

Node that I aligned the bones so that they point +Z to the top and +Y to the back, as in Blender's world coordinates.

In Pose Mode, select an eye's controller bone, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select its deform bone, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > Track To constraint. Set the axes to -Y track and +Z up :

[image]

Repeat for the other eye's bones.

Optional: after adding the constraints, the eyes deformation bones probably rotated to properly orient themselves to the control bone. This effectively means that their default pose isn't the same as their tracking pose. It isn't a big deal, but if you want to fix this: for both constrained bones, hover the constraint with your mouse, hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to duplicate it, hover the duplicate and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to apply it as the default pose.

To prevent the eyes from rotating up and down, select the main control bone, and lock it Z location in the sidebar:

[image]

You can do the same on the individual eyes control bones.

Alternatively:

You might want to be able to animate the height of the eyes. Instead of locking the controllers's Z location, you can use drivers:

Select an eye's controller, <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> its Z location > *Copy As New Driver*. Select the eye's deform bone > <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> its Z location > *Paste Driver*.

Replicate on other eye.

Now you can move the individual eyes' controllers up and down to change the eyes' height.

[image]

[image]