# Changing image textures with keyframes

Tags: animation, node-editor, keyframes, shader-nodes

currently I am using the alpha channel of an image to give a robot face some eyes with changeable material:

[image]

Now I want to animate the eyes and I exported 7 frames with different looks of the eyes and grouped them together in one node group.
Is there any way to select the output of a node group with a "keyframeable" value? :D

[image: Node Editor]

Comment: Here is a question about 2D rigging, maybe you'll find a solution? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object

Comment: I just found out how to do it a few minutes after I posted my question :D
Its also one solution in the question you send me (thx for that )
I can do it with the image sequence function. I just needed to change the dropdown "Single Image" inside the Image texture node to "Image Sequence". Then I can select the different images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to change the dropdown "Single Image" inside the Image texture node to "Image Sequence". Then I can change the offset value and keyframe it.

[image]

Comment: don't forget to come back in (i think) 48 hours to accept your own answer with the ✔️ button 