# how to animate image on action editor

Tags: animation, rigging, image-sequence

I tried to animate my character's face with image sequences. I got setting up the sequences covered, but how do I animate them on action editor. Each animation for my game character will have different face animations like blinking in idle state, xx eyes when dying, or confident eyes when attacking. How do I animate different face animations with the action editor? (B.T.W. I'm doing the same for the mouth)

Comment: Hello you just need to put some keyframes on the value, what method exactly have you chosen? I've answered something that may be similar here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object

Comment: I kind of set that part up but thanks. I want to animate certain actions editor and the dope sheet doesn't really do that. Also I'm using 3.6

Comment: It should work, make sure that both the node and the head are selected

Comment: I tried doing it but I couldn't see the keyframes on the action editor. Another thing is that I can't make a second animation for it. like I can only do blinking. Finally, When I do try animating it sometimes it would go through all the other animations before it reaches the one I assign it to.