# How to switch textures/add sevral on top

Tags: texturing

Im making a roblox rigging animation in blender.
Like a animation I want still pngs that change but I want the face to be on top of the texture?
here's the video link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nOECArFhFw
Like how the still pngs change.
blender 4.0 windows

Comment: Hello if you're talking about face expressions, see my answer here, I give several solutions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object If you'retalking about something else please be more specific

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.