How to create animation ready pupils on ellipsoid-shaped eyes?

I have cartoony character with a pupil which I want to be able to feely move around the eyeball without losing it's shape. I tried animating an UV but couldn't figure out how to unwrap it to avoid distortion. I also tried adding a mesh with shrinkwrap modifier which is much more promising however still loses shape as it's stretched and bent if moved from one side to the other and it also glitches into the eyeball on some points of the eye.

Distortion example ^
Anyone knows how to fix the shrinkwrap method to avoid distortion or maybe another method entirely to achieve this? All I need is a pupil that can be animated and not get distorted.

maybe instead of a Shrinkwrap use a texture? See my answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object

Tried texture. Massive deformations

One way to do that is to model your eyes as a regular sphere, and your pupil being either a part of that sphere duplicated and offset, or a texture:

Then, make a simple rig with one bone for the eye, and another child one. If you made your pupil as a second mesh, weight both meshes to each bone as the above screenshot. If you have just one mesh with a pupil texture, simply weight paint the whole mesh to the Pupil bone.
And then you can use bone scaling or object modifiers below the Armature Deform modifier to shape the eyes the way you want.
It works because the armature's deformation of your pupil is done before the re-shaping of your eyes, so when it is still a simple sphere around which your pupil is simply rotating.
Bonescale-based technique
It works best if your eyes' shape can be obtained from simple XYZ scaling. Yours seem to be a sphere flattened on Y and X and then rotated a bit, so it could be just enough:

It's probably the simplest solution, although limited in what shape you can get, but it should be exportable outside of Blender most of the time AFAIK.
A slight downside of this technique is that you could accidentally reset your eyes' scale and rotation when you want to make a new fresh animation. So to counter that, don't forget to store your eyes' "default" pose in the asset browser. (Do not apply the pose as rest pose.)
Modifier-based technique
This requires each of your eyes meshes (with their pupil meshes) to be their own object, separate from each other and the rest of the mesh.
For modifiers, I think the lattice works best for this. Add a Lattice object around your eye object. Add a Lattice modifier on your eyes objects. Then deform the lattices in edit mode, you can add more subdivision in the lattice properties. And it allows more funky deformation:

You will need to parent the lattice object to the eye bone, otherwise moving the eye bone will distort the eyes unexpectedly. For this, select the lattice object, then ⇧ Shift select the armature, ↹ Tab into Pose Mode, select the eye bone, and hit ⎈ CtrlP > Set Parent to Bone:

Note however that all this modifier-based technique can't be easily exported outside of Blender, since deforming mesh by other means than shapekeys and armature deform isn't standard, and no exchange format supports them. You could export it as a mesh cache using Alembic or USD, but this is essentially taking a snapshot of your mesh at each frame, instead of keeping your mesh deformed by an armature and letting the target software computing that deformation.

If anyone goes the lattice route pair it with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hq92JvHq2g
